# How to restrict/stop keyboard from appearing when you click a readOnly textfield inside an exposedDropdownMenuBox with an exposedDropdownMenu

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am unable to stop the soft keyboard from popping up when I click a readOnly textField which is inside an exposedDropDownBox. I have the composable as below:

```
@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
private fun AgeDropDownRow(context: Context) {
    val ageArray = arrayOf("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedItemIndex by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {

        ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
            expanded = expanded,
            onExpandedChange = { expanded = !expanded },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        ) {
            var age by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
            TextField(
                value = ageArray[selectedItemIndex],
                onValueChange = { },
                label = { Text(text = "Select Age") },
                readOnly = true,
                trailingIcon = {
                    ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded)
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .menuAnchor(),
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(imeAction = ImeAction.None)
             // Add this line
            )

            ExposedDropdownMenu(
                expanded = expanded,
                onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }
            ) {
                ageArray.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        text = {
                            Text(
                                text = item,
                                fontWeight = if (index == selectedItemIndex) FontWeight.Bold else null
                            )
                        },
                        onClick = {
                            selectedItemIndex = index
                            expanded = false
                            Toast.makeText(context, item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    )
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I have tried to set the ImeAction to ImeAction.none in keyboard option but that doesn't helped.
I am stuck at this issue, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You've already set imeAction to ImeAction.None, but you also need to set keyboardController to null. Here's the modified code:

```
modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .menuAnchor(),
keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
    imeAction = ImeAction.None,
    keyboardController = null // This line prevents the keyboard from showing up
)
```

By setting keyboardController to null, you're telling Compose not to show the keyboard when this TextField is clicked

Comment: Cannot find a parameter with this name: keyboardController in KeyboardOptions.

Comment: Have you used a comma to separate both attributes ie
 imeAction = ImeAction.None ,
 keyboardController = null